# Rails association skip update associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback

```
class City<ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :template, class_name:'TmplLocation'
  after_initialize :_init
  private
  def _init

    self.template = TmplLocation.find(18) if !self.template
  end
end
```

And that's what happens in console:

```
>Loc.first.template
  City Load (29.8ms)  SELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations` WHERE `locations`.`type` IN ('City') LIMIT 1
  TmplLocation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations` WHERE `locations`.`type` IN ('TmplLocation') AND `locations`.`location_id` = 23 LIMIT 1
  TmplLocation Load (34.8ms)  SELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations` WHERE `locations`.`type` IN ('TmplLocation') AND `locations`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 18]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.7ms)  UPDATE `locations` SET `location_id` = 23, `updated_at` = '2013-06-11 10:47:11' WHERE `locations`.`type` IN ('TmplLocation') AND `locations`.`id` = 18
   (41.4ms)  COMMIT
```

You see? It updates the *TmplLocation* so now it is constantly associated with this exact city.
I want only use the *TmplLocation* instance in this City
How to skip update stage??

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
class City<ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :template, class_name:'TmplLocation', :conditions => { :id => 18 }
end
```

For more options see this

[guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Your solution loads one and only one default always.
I need to use the default one only if there is no override.

Comment: your default TmplLocation is same for all city ?

Comment: Mostly, but should be an option to override per City.
In general, why rails updates the object when I just assign it to the property of some other object?

Comment: I am still not clear what you are trying to implement but I think you want to assign template to city if it is not present , if that's the case then you are using wron callback , use before_save instead of after_initialize

Comment: I don't want to save the association in database - this case is clear.
I need to use default one only if City has no template associated with it.

thanks in advance